# How to set Meteor WebSocket port for clients?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, meteor, port

How can I set the port WebSocket will be listening on? I'm trying to deploy Meteor on OpenShift, but there they have a nodejs-proxy server that listen on port 8000 instead 80, and redirect to my Meteor daemon. It is working since a manually created WebSocket object works fine.

I've set ROOT_URL but without success. It appears on the browser as defined bellow:

```
process.env.ROOT_URL = 'http://' + process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS + ':8000'
```

I'm using this quickstart: https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-meteorjs-quickstart. See file meteorshim.js for reference.

Everything works fine, including long-polling.

Comment: Have you ever got this working? I'm struggling with the same issue. Could you post the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I struggled with this for a while now and I tried different things. The solution that worked for me in OpenShift was this:

**Set the DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL variable**

```
//for http
process.env.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL = 'http://' + process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS + ':8000'
//for ssl
process.env.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL = 'https://' + process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS + ':8443'
```

According to [this blog post](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/paas-websockets)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the environmental variable `PORT`

so I guess:

```
process.env.PORT = 8000
process.env.ROOT_URL = 'http://' + process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS
```

To set websockets on a different port specifically and have meteor run on a different port I'm not too sure this is possible yet.

Comment: Still not possible. This port is for HTTP requests only, not WebSocket.

Comment: @caruccio this sets both ports, you can use nginx to proxy your app to a different port I guess http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html. The other option is to modify meteor here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/livedata/stream_server.js and use your own port instead of the /websocket endpoint

Comment: You are right. I realized that 10 minutes after posting, but stackoverflow didn't allowed me to edit it.