# Open a Websocket connection from Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, websocket, npm

How can we open a Websockets connection from Meteor?

Can we do something like:

```
ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost/path');
ws.on('open', function() {
    ws.send('something');
});
ws.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
});
```

> Error: ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined

---

**Using socket.io npm package**

```
var io = Meteor.require('socket.io')
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
```

> Error: TypeError: Object # has no method 'connect'

---

**Using ws npm package**

```
var WebSocket = Meteor.require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost');
```

> Error: Error: Cannot find module '../build/default/bufferutil'

Answer (score 4):

I created a new Meteor package `joncursi:socket-io-client` to solve this problem. Please see https://atmospherejs.com/joncursi/socket-io-client for more detail and example usage. Since I've bundled the NPM binaries into a package for you, you don't have to worry about installing NPM packages, declaring `NPM.require()` dependencies, etc. And best of all, you can deploy to `.meteor.com` without a hitch.

Comment: Is there a way of using this for ordinary websockets connections without a socket.io connection?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called [Meteor Streams](http://arunoda.github.io/meteor-streams/), that can let you do something similar, using the existing meteor websocket to connect to the local server:

```
chatStream = new Meteor.Stream('chat');

if(Meteor.isClient) {
  sendChat = function(message) {
    chatStream.emit('message', message);
    console.log('me: ' + message);
  };

  chatStream.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log('user: ' + message);
  });
}
```

I'm not sure you wanted to connect to another server or the local one, if its another one you can use the example you have provided. I would recommend using something else like SockJS or socket.io in the case where websockets aren't permitted on the client side (and hence websocket emulation is required).

Comment: I will like to connect to a non-Meteor Websocket service. Using my example, I get the error `ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined`. I tried the `socket.io` npm package but using `Meteor.require('socket.io').connect('http://localhost'), I get the error `Object #<Object> has no method 'connect'`

Comment: Are you doing this on the server on client side?

Comment: Try using the faye-websockets npm module if from the server @ https://npmjs.org/package/faye-websocket

Comment: I'm trying this on the client side, trying to connect to a WebSocket server.

Comment: Client side meaning from the web browser? or the server side of meteor acting as a client? Does your WebSocket code work in the js console?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can use npm package on client side like this

Comment: Sorry, client side meaning the Meteor server acting as a WebSocket client. `faye-websocket` works, but theres a problem connecting to the WS server, its giving a message `destroying non-socket.io upgrade`. Without access to the WS server configs, is it possible for `faye-websocket` client to work around this problem?

Comment: This is happening because your server is a socket.io server, if you had a websocket server this wouldn't happen. This npm module should help you with a socket.io server @ https://npmjs.org/package/socket.io-client

Answer (score 0):

According to this question's answer which refers to an openshift blog post, 
you answer is:
(question : [How to set Meteor WebSocket port for clients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451428/how-to-set-meteor-websocket-port-for-clients))

> I struggled with this for a while now and I tried different things.
>   The solution that worked for me in OpenShift was this:
>
> Set the DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL variable
>
> ```
> //for http
> process.env.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL = 'http://' + process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS + ':8000'
> //for ssl
> process.env.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL = 'https://' + process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS + ':8443'
> ```
>
> According to this blog post:
>   https://www.openshift.com/blogs/paas-websockets

Answer (score 0):

You can try here is the solution:
https://github.com/Akryum/meteor-socket-io